# How configure MockMvc request that it will as request sent after my html form submit

Tags: java, testing, spring-mvc, mocking, spring-test

I have this html spring  form:

```
<form:form action="addVacancy" modelAttribute="myVacancy">
        <form:label path="name">name</form:label>
        <form:input path="name" ></form:input>
        <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
        <br>
        <form:label path="description">description</form:label>
        <form:input path="description" id="nameInput"></form:input>
        <form:errors path="description" cssClass="error" />
        <br>
        <form:label path="date">date</form:label>
        <input type="date" name="date" />
        <form:errors path="date" cssClass="error" />
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="add" />
    </form:form>
```

I handle this form by this method:

```
@RequestMapping("/addVacancy")
    public ModelAndView addVacancy(@ModelAttribute("myVacancy") @Valid Vacancy vacancy,BindingResult result, Model model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            model.addAttribute("message","validation error");
            return new ModelAndView("vacancyDetailsAdd");
        }
        vacancyService.add(vacancy);
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:goToVacancyDetails");
        mv.addObject("idVacancy", vacancy.getId());
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("message", "added correctly at "+ new Date());
        return mv;
    }
```

**Using MockMvc How I can pass same data as from this html form?**

```
@Test
public void testMethod(){
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/addVacancy");
    //what must I  write here?
    ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MockHttpServletRequestBuilder contains methods for that.
you can use

```
get("/addVacancy").requestAttr("name", "namefromform")...
```

or other methods like param(), sessionAttr() if needed